# Fastest rails test runner: spork and zentest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests, autotest, zentest

I ran across a thread about [slow rspec tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770/why-is-rspec-so-slow-under-rails) that made me wonder which rails test runner configuration will result in the fastest running recurring tests?

I'm aware that [ZenTest](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest) / [autotest-rails](http://github.com/seattlerb/autotest-rails) can be used in conjunction with [spork](http://github.com/timcharper/spork), but is that the fastest option?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to tell you about my experiences.. even tho this doesn't answer you question. I don't have experience with autotest yet, so can't comment on that. This is Rails 3 with RSpec, DatabaseCleaner and FactoryGirl. Here are the results without and with spork:

```
Finished in 0.22748 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures

real    0m9.541s
user    0m8.733s
sys 0m0.772s



Finished in 0.24727 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures

real    0m0.605s
user    0m0.200s
sys 0m0.080s
```

So, from 9.541 seconds down to half a second. Roughly a ten fold performance boost.

Comment: Wow. Huge difference.  I'm planning on doing some tests but it will probably be a couple more weeks before I can get to it.